# str replace error

Tags: php

I have an error on the following code:

```
$name = "Bush Dvd Player";

print "<a href='?name".print str_replace(' ', '-', $name).".html' >Previous</a>";
```

On the page is shows the following:

Car-Parts-and-Accessories however not in a url format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str_replace()` returns a string that will be concatenated to the output string, therefore there is no need for the additional `print`, so just omit it:

```
print "<a href='?name" . str_replace(' ', '-', $name) . ".html' >Previous</a>";
```

Your old code would print out the result of `str_replace`, followed by the concatenation of the first string literal, along with the return value of `print str_replace(' ', '-', $name)`, and then then 2nd string literal.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is your inner print statement is evaluated before the outer print statement. To fix this you should simply remove the second `print`.